# A Kings' Witness

Tags: riddle, rhyme

## A Kings' Witness

> **I was there when kings were born**
>
> **Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn**
>
> **The strongest fell in my presence**
>
> **Consequences ignored in my absence**
>
> **The corrupt have plenty to give**
>
> **Given too much it's hard to live**
>
> **Some have reached out and felt me**
>
> **But none have ever touched me**

What am I?

Added lines:

> **The corrupt have plenty to give**
>
> **Given too much it's hard to live**

Comment: rot13(Vf vg zbarl?)

Comment: @UnidentifiedX nice guess, but it wouldn't quite fit.

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> Corruption

I was there when kings were born

> Corruption has always been there since the start of mankind

Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn

> Corruption can lead to *serious* consequences

The strongest fell in my presence

> The strongest Empires/Dynasties fell because there was corruption everywhere, even within the king's palace

Consequences ignored in my absence

> Nothing to ignore when there's no corruption :)

Some have reached out and felt me

> Bribery? Some have felt the effects of bribing someone succesfully

But none have ever touched me

> You can't touch corruption, cant you?

**OR**

You are:

> Death

I was there when kings were born

> Duh!

Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn

> Who wants to die?

The strongest fell in my presence

> The wealthiest, strongest, most powerful, all will eventually die

Consequences ignored in my absence

> No death, nothing to worry about!

Some have reached out and felt me

> Dead people

But none have ever touched me

> You can't touch death, can't you?

Comment: +1 for great answers, but not what I had in mind.  I added two more lines to narrow the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're

> Guilt

**I was there when kings were born**

> Guilt is as old as rational thinking

**Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn**

> Guilt is one of if not the worst feeling you can have

**The strongest fell in my presence**

> Guilt lingers and you can't do anything about it

**Consequences ignored in my absence**

> With no guilt, you don't take responsibility of your actions

**The corrupt have plenty to give**

> Wrongdoers have plenty to feel guilt for

**Given too much it's hard to live**

> Guilt can drive people insane

**Some have reached out and felt me**

> It's not unusual to feel guilt

**But none have ever touched me**

> You cannot touch guilt

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be:

> Greed (in general strong lust for something)

I was there when kings were born:

> Most of them would have a deep longing for something

Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn :

> Most would have known many stories about the greed's consequences and yet theirs is innate, they mark their guilt against the stories they have heard and try to avoid it

The strongest fell in my presence :

> Many strong men fell due to greed

Consequences ignored in my absence :

> The mind will be at peace with the absence of greed

The corrupt have plenty to give :

> Corrupt have a great degreed of greed for money

Given too much it's hard to live :

> Once the mind clings to so much greed for something, it never satisfies and hence the mind is NEVER at peace and hence it is hard to live.

Some have reached out and felt me :

> Some felt the greed

But none have ever touched me :

> Greed is a feeling that is to be felt and that can't be touched

Answer (score 0):

> Blood

matches all except the last line.

I was there when kings were born

> Blood at childbirth

Yet all avoided me lest they know my scorn

> Not touching the placenta or the newborn until it's cleaned up

The strongest fell in my presence

> Wounded e.g. in battle

Consequences ignored in my absence

> Not having enough blood is terminal

Some have reached out and felt me

> self-evident

But none have ever touched me

> (doesn't fit this one)

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: @Jason_: yes me too, but it seemed to fit well 5/6 of the clues.

Comment: I've added two lines to narrow down your search!

Comment: @Jason: lines 7,8 actually do fit this non-solution. But I'll stop at that.